# Tienda en Prestashop (1.7.5) no reconoce tema ni imagenes

Tags: php, css, prestashop, prestashop1.7

Tengo creada una multi-tienda en Prestashop (1.7.5) , el problema esta en que cada vez que añado una nueva tienda a la multi-tienda se me crea sin ningún estilo ni funcionalidad ,adjuntare una foto de como esta al momento.

[image: Tienda sin funcionalidad]

He realizado lo siguiente sin tener éxito por el momento:

1. Verificar que todos los archivos del tema e imágenes se encuentren
   en la carpeta del servidor para que puedan ser accedidas y
   consumidas.
2. Colocar permisos de 755 a todas las carpetas y de 644 a todos los
   archivos de prestashop como indica la documentación oficial.
3. De igual manera aunque no recomendable he dado permisos 777 a toda
   la carpeta de prestashop pero de ninguna manera se solventa.